# How to make network connection to a Windows machine from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, remote

I want to open file which is on windows machine on \\192.168.1.188\Media\sdff.vdi

How can I do this in Linux 14.04 ? Firstly, I would like to download this file, but it's the question. How?

Comment: What do you mean? Apache or Samba on windows server which this file is stored or my enviroment?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are sharing the Media folder on windows and that you have samba installed on your linux machine, you could, from `nautilus` do this.

Go to `Connect to Server` and then in the server address, type:

```
smb://192.168.1.188/Media
```

That should opened the shared '`Media` folder.
It might pop you for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have shared the folder in windows you can do this from terminal:

```
mkdir -pv ~/mnt/share
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.188/media$ ~/mnt/share/ -o username=<username-you-have-on-windows-machine>
```

You will then be prompted for the username you have for your windows user. After that you can find the contents of your share in `~/mnt/share/`.